# Как открыть окно выбора метода ввода из командной строки в android?

Tags: android, python, shell

В Android (java) есть код для открытия окна выбора метода ввода:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Как вызвать это окно из командной строки?
Знаю, что для этой цели есть команда:

```
$ service
```

Usage: service [-h|-?]
       service list
       service check SERVICE
       service call SERVICE CODE [i32 N | i64 N | f N | d N | s16 STR ] ...
Options:
   i32: Write the 32-bit integer N into the send parcel.
   i64: Write the 64-bit integer N into the send parcel.
   f:   Write the 32-bit single-precision number N into the send parcel.
   d:   Write the 64-bit double-precision number N into the send parcel.
   s16: Write the UTF-16 string STR into the send parcel.

Не могу подобрать правильные аргументы для получения ожидаемого результата.

И можно реализовать это также в скрипте Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ сам. Команда: `service call input_method 10` открывает окно выбора метода ввода.
А в python можно реализовать так: `import subprocess
subprocess.call(["service", "call", "input_method", "10"])`